# Does the username need whitespace after for the notification to work?

Tags: support, notifications, comment-replies

It's difficult to test this without setting up a new account, and asking myself a question...

When including a `@username` in a comment, does it need whitespace after the username for the notification to work?

For instance, if I say something like...

> Thanks @username, that worked perfectly

... will `@username` get the notification?

Comment: reply to me and I'll tell you :P

Comment: Thanks @OGHaza, that's a good idea!

Comment: got the notification :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that @OGHaza, it's put my mind at ease :-)

Comment: @OGHaza_You_Need_Only_First_Three_Letters_For_Notification.

Comment: @him were you expecting extra letters to still notify me?

Comment: From the faq: *Single trailing punctuation such as a dot, comma or colon is ignored, like `@name`, yes works, but `@name`... no does not.*

Comment: @OGHaza... you will not be notified now. :-)

Comment: Thank @ShadowWizard, that's really useful.  I'd completely forgotten that the notification would also work with a single commenter.  I'll have to remember the `...` rule, as I quite often do that

Comment: Why don't you update your answer, @OGHaza, with this notification... as that will prove you got it with other commentators on the question

Comment: Yes, @AlienArrays, I did get that notification

Comment: Sorry, @AlienArrays, I've just realised that I would get your notification ANYWAY, even if you hadn't put my username, as I am the original poster

Comment: youtellme@AlienArraysdidit? <- hims056 reply to be earlier didn't notify me so I imagine the additional letters on the end are a deal breaker.

Comment: @AlienArrays nope, it was considered one word or more likely partial email address ;)

Comment: Author of the post always gets a notification for any comment on his post @AlienArrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exhibit A**

[image]

**Exhibit B**

[image]

Additional information gathered from the comments:

- If you're the only commenter or the post author, you'll be notified whether they @Reply you or not.
- Single punctuation marks are ignored, but multiple are not so `@OGHaza,` works but not `@OGHaza...`
- You only need the first 3 letters of the username to notify the user `@OGH`

Comment: Even if he didn't write your name with `@`, you would have get the notification since there was no other commentators at that time.

Comment: haha I had no idea, ah well...

Comment: updated but then I noticed the duplicate link in the comments that explains it all much better ;)

Comment: Indeed, but at least you get a few reps for this answer :) Thanks for your help